# SUM() in WHERE in MYSQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

Following table structure name: table

```
quantity      price 
  100         30.00 
  50          15.00 
  25          25.00
  25          24.00
  25          23.00
```

I want to select the rows
`WHERE SUM(quantity)<=90 AND price<26.00`

the output should be

```
quantity      price 
   50         15.00
   25         23.00
   25         24.00
```

I want to select all rows which are necessary to fullfill the quantity 90

WHERE and SUM doesn't seem to work

Comment: Aggregate function should be used on having?

Comment: When you use SUM all records been added. Total = 225 never minus than 90. remove SUM clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUM()` is an aggregation function and you provide no aggregate, so this is bound to fail.

What you seem to want is a running total, this can easily be achieved:

```
SELECT
  quantity, price, 
  @rt:=@rt+quantity AS runningtotal
FROM
  `table`
  INNER JOIN (SELECT @rt:=0) AS init ON 1=1
WHERE
  price<26.00
  AND @rt<=90
```

See the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38248fd/3/0)

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean - `WHERE quantity <=90 AND price<26.00`

Comment: Judging from *"I want to select all rows which are necessary to fullfill the quantity 90"* the OP wants to select rows up to a running total, not by a single row's value

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an aggregate function (SUM) in a where clause.
It needs to be in a having clause.

```
Where price < 26
Having Sum(Quantity) <= 90
```

But this will only work if you have a group by statement otherwise it won't know which rows to sum

Comment: Judging from *"I want to select all rows which are necessary to fullfill the quantity 90"* the OP wants to select rows up to a running total, not group all, then filter by sum.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use an aggregate function in there where clause, this is not allowed. Instead you need to use [HAVING](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php) clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT quantity, price
FROM table
GROUP BY quantity
HAVING SUM(quantity) <= 90 AND price < 26.00
```

**EDIT**

I believe what you really just need here is to get rid of the SUM function, based on your example you're not summing anything, you're just making sure that the quantity column is less than 90. Use this:

```
SELECT quantity, price
FROM table
WHERE quantity <= 90 AND price < 26
ORDER BY quantity DESC, price ASC // Based on your example for expected output
```

If you really do need the SUM function for this problem, though, the reason it won't work in the where clause is because it is an aggregate function. See the article I linked for more information.

Comment: group by quantity then sum the quantity is not a good example

Comment: Good point, but isn't the group by statement required? Feel free to edit with another solution, I'm definitely curious for the best answer to this one.

Comment: Judging from *"I want to select all rows which are necessary to fullfill the quantity 90"* the OP wants to select rows up to a running total, not by a single row's value

Comment: But that doesn't match OP's expected output table.